# Conversion from MimeMessage to byte array

Tags: java, mime, mime-message

I need to convert MimeMessage into byte array, but while converting some characters are not coded correctly. Code lookis like this:

```
// message is MimeMessage
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

This conversion doesn't work correctly, as output I'm receving wrong formatted email body:

```
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=3D"en" lang=3D"en"
   >
<body style=3D"background-color: #ffffff;"  >
```

...

3D should not be present in this (xmlns=**3D**"http:). I could remove it but this is not a safe solution, I might accidentally remove some content from the email body.

Any tip may help.

Comment: this has nothing to do with serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mime message contains Quoted-Printable Encoding, see [MIME RFC 1521](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt?number=1521), so you need to decode it before saving it.

You should be able to use javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decode for this.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.