# How to save an Email as Text

Tags: java, email, encoding, character-encoding

As backup I want to store the original received emails that were fetched with Java.

My current approach is to use the writeTo method:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage;
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
     mimeMessage.writeTo(out);
     String rawContent = out.toString();
     FileUtiles.writeStringToFile("email.txt", rawContent);
}
```

But when I send this Email via Telnet:

```
Return-Path: <jones@jibjab.jinga>
To: <indianer@jones.com>
Subject: test special chars
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=_1c4a520f54326063ea347cd3da780d5a"

--=_1c4a520f54326063ea347cd3da780d5a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="IBM850"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test
ä ü Ö ß
Test

--=_1c4a520f54326063ea347cd3da780d5a
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archive.zip"

--=_1c4a520f54326063ea347cd3da780d5a--
```

The "ä ü Ö ß" part is broken in the Textfile (replaced by "� � � �". In Outlook everything looks fine.

My understanding of the Email protocol is, that only ascii chars are sent.
Why isn't it working, and what can I do to have it working?

EDIT:
The Email should be in it's original state as backup if anything goes wrong. As the email protocol works with only ASCII chars, there should be no issue saving the whole email.
Quoted printable Encoding (like in the [supposed dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464686/conversion-from-mimemessage-to-byte-array) I much prefer over this 7bit stuff, but I don't have control over the Emails coming in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion from MimeMessage to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464686/conversion-from-mimemessage-to-byte-array)

Comment: Your email is encoded.  You can try decoding it using a tool like `javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decode`

Comment: I would much prefer not the decode anything, just save it as it was received. MimeUtility is working fine is most of the cases, but sometimes not. So with decoding I am adding complexity I would really like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't convert the message to string - rather let mimeMessage.writeTo(fileOutputStream) - write directly to a FileOutputStream. (Converting to string puts you in risk of charset problems)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't expect to have issues just by a conversion in between, but it did solve my problem!